# Why is Scala coercing type from Char to Double?

Tags: scala

The following code

```
object testType extends App {
  def func(x:Int) = if(x==0) 1.0 else 'c'
  println(func(0))
  println(func(1))
}
```

results in

```
1.0
99.0
```

At first when I wrote this, I thought Scala was not going to allow such a function but it interpreted the function as `(Int) => Double`. This feels like type coercion.

If I substitute the `'c'` for `"c"` in the function above, it actually returns

```
1.0
c
```

where the function is now interpreted as `(Int) => Any`

Questions: if Scala is strongly typed, why did the first example with `'c'` returned a Double and why the difference between `(Int) => Double` and `(Int) => Any` for the two examples?

Answer (score 6):

There is a relationship between types in Scala called ["weak conformance"](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#weak-conformance). `Char` weakly conforms to `Double` (because it weakly conforms to `Int` which weakly conforms to `Double`). The type of `if (<cond>) then <e1> else <e2>` is [defined to be the weak least upper bound (wlub) of types of `<e1>` and `<e2>`](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (there is a similar rule for other expressions with many branches: `match` and `try/catch`). The wlub of `Char` and `Double` is `Double`; the wlub of `String` and `Double` is `Any`.

Answer (score 1):

Scala does implicit conversions between types where necessary. Usually it does this through some implicit conversion defined anywhere in scope (most of the implicit conversions are in scala.Predef which is imported by default)

In order to see all available implicit conversions do this in the repl:

```
:implicits -v
```

However, if you do that, you will see that there is no implicit conversion available from char2Double. So whats going on? Here, scala compiler resorts to another type of conversion called [numeric widening](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions):

> If ee has a primitive number type which weakly conforms to the expected type, it is widened to the expected type using one of the numeric conversion methods toShort, toChar, toInt, toLong, toFloat, toDouble defined here.

So, as @Alexey pointed out in his answer that chars weakly conform to Doubles, the char 'c' gets converted to a Double by applying 'c'.toDouble numeric widening conversion.

Also, you can disable implicit conversions that are defined in Predef like this:

```
// disable int to Integer conversion
import scala.Predef.{int2Integer => _}
```

<s>However, am not sure whether the numeric widening conversions can be disabled.</s>

As pointed by @pedrorijo91, numeric widening can also be prevented by adding the suitable scalac flags: -Ywarn-numeric-widen & -Xfatal-warnings

Comment: there's a compilation flag on scalac for that `-Ywarn-numeric-widen`. More info at http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-compiler-review-code-warnings/

Comment: and if you want to 'disable it', you may also use `-Xfatal-warnings` that will fail the compilation if numeric widening happened

Comment: @pedrorijo91 Thanks for the suggestion and the article link :)